# Determining if a 3D point is in front of a pair of stereo camera, given their essential matrix

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, stereo-3d, multiple-views

I'm trying to obtain the 3D metric reconstruction of the points I have in two different views of my scene by means of a pair of iPhone 4S (a rudimental stereo system).

To do so, I did calibrate the cameras, estimate the fundamental matrix and obtained an estimate of the essential matrix. Now, in Hartley&Zisserman "Multiple View Geometry in CV" book, I see that to any given E, they correspond 4 canonical cameras pairs, of which only one reconstructs as the "actual" stereo configuration.

The problem is that they say [cit.]"...the reconstructed point will be in front of both cameras in one of these four solutions only. Thus, testing with a single point to determine if it is in front of both cameras is sufficient to decide between the four different solutions for the camera matrix P'. ..."

Given that I know F, K_left and K_right, how does one establish whether a 3D point is in front of both cameras or not?

Thanks,

Riccardo

Answer (score 5):

You can get the camera rotation and translation from essential matrix. So, you have the camera matrix P = [R, -R*t]. To test if point X = (x, y, z, 1) is in front of the camera, compute X' = P*X. X' = (x', y', z') will be position of point if camera is in the origin, looking toward z direction. So, if z' is positive, then X' is in front of the camera and X is in front of camera P. Else X is behind P.

Comment: Note, that you would need to reconstruct this 3d point from the matches that you have.